# dup return value is always zero

Tags: c, file, posix, dup

I would to know why does *dup* always return zeroes in the following code (in which a file is opened, than 10 dup are done successively) :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void main()
{
        int i,fdo,fdd;

        if((fdo = open("test", O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0666)) < 0)
        {
                        perror("main open");
                        return;
        }

        printf("main open: %d\n",fdo);


        for(i=0; i< 10;i++)
        {
                if((fdd = dup(fdo) < 0 )) {
                        perror("dup");
                        return ;
                }
                printf("opened %d, duped: %d \n", fdo,fdd);

        }

}
```

When i run the program (on linux 2.6.32-279.19.1.el6.i686, Netbsd or Solaris 5.9)
, i get the following results:

```
main open: 3
opened 3, duped: 0 
opened 3, duped: 0 
opened 3, duped: 0 
opened 3, duped: 0 
opened 3, duped: 0 
opened 3, duped: 0 
opened 3, duped: 0 
opened 3, duped: 0 
opened 3, duped: 0 
opened 3, duped: 0
```

The return value of dup is always "0"?!

Althought the man page state that the return value should be the file descriptor:

> RETURN VALUE
>          On success, these system calls return the new descriptor.  On error, -1 is returned, and errno is set appropriately.

I don't understand why i get always "0", knowing that i didn't use the *close* operation.

Please, help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is in your condition:

```
(fdd = dup(fdo) < 0)
```

The variable `fdd` becomes the result of `dup(fdo) < 0`. You need to check your parentheses:

```
(fdd = dup(fdo)) < 0
```